# SELECT DISTINCT with a JOIN and unnormalized tables

Tags: sql, distinct

I've got two tables

```
id    |    name
1     |    foo
2     |    foo
2     |    foo       <- duplicated id
3     |    bar
```

and

```
id    |    value
1     |    100
1     |    200
2     |    300      <- same value and id
2     |    300      <- 
3     |    500
```

I need to get the rows from the second table for each id with name foo:

```
1     100
1     200
2     300
2     300
```

The id/name table isn't normalized and I can't do anything about that. So I need to select the distinct ids from table 1 and non distinct id/values from table 2. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which version of SQL you are using.  The following should work with any version:

```
select tabl2.*
from (select distinct id, name
      from table1
     ) join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.name = 'foo'
```